# Was Lady Fatimah (a.s.) higher than many other men? (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, fatima-zahra

Was Lady Fatimah (a.s.) higher than many other men? (Shia view)
Is there any narration or source to prove the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no doubt about the high status of bibi zehra(A.S.). For instance, look at the following hadith (narration) that Prophet Muhammad (S) said regarding his daughter (Fatimah (s.a.)):

> Prophet (sawa):**'Fatimah is the mother of her father!'** Bihar al-Anwar, vol. 43, p. 19; this nickname 'Ummu Abeeha', mother of her father, is included as one of the names by which she used to be known - see 'Awalim al-Zahra, p. 69.
>
> **'Aisha said: 'I had not seen any one who was more resembling the
>   Messenger of Allah in his speech, conduct and manners as Fatimah; when
>   she used to enter (his house) he would stand up for her, take her hand
>   and kiss it and make her sit in his sitting place; and when he used to
>   enter (her house) she would stand up for him, take his hand and kiss
>   it and make him sit in her sitting place'**  A'yan al-Shi'ah, Sayyid Muhsin al-Amin al-'Amily, Dar al-Ta'aruf, Beirut, Vol.1, p. 307.
>
> **> 'And they give away food, out of love for Him, to the poor and the
>   orphan and the captive. We feed you only for God's sake, we intend not
>   of you any recompense, nor thanks! Verily, we dread from our Lord, a
>   stern day of distress. So will God guard them from the evil of that
>   day and cause them to meet freshness and pleasure. And shall
>   recompense them, for what they endured with patience, with garden and
>   silk.' (Qur'an 76:8-12)**

Commentators, from different Muslim sects, said that these honourable verses referred to Ali, Fatimah, al-Hasan and al-Husain (as).

Comment: Welldone, it was a persuasive reply, although it could be with more example and illustration; anyhow it was a nice answer. Good luck.